# GetSaveAsFilename using a cell value as file title

Tags: excel, vba, save-as

Please HELP!
I'm using the “GetSaveAsFilname” function to save my file using the value of a specific cell as title, this is created by a formula.
I’m not the only one using the file, so the saving path most be selected by the user.
Most of the times it works, but sometimes the title is blank, and the user need to write it down from zero.
Below my code:

```
Sub SaveTool()

Dim Name As String
Dim sFileSaveName As Variant

Name = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Analisis").Range("G1")
sFileSaveName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=Name, FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xlsm), *.xlsm")

If sFileSaveName <> False Then
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs sFileSaveName
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Try renaming `Name` to something more unique like `SaveName` or `G1Name`. Maybe there is an issue due to `Name` being confused for an object property or the [Name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.name) Object or another variable with the same defined name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the suggested name is blank, the issue is with `InitialFileName` which is set to `Name`. So the issue is that `Name` is sometimes blank. `Name` gets it's value from `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Analisis").Range("G1")`.

Two unreliable parts of this are:

1. `ActiveWorkbook` instead of `ThisWorkbook` or `Application.Workbooks(index)`. If the user clicks on other workbooks before executing the macro, then `ActiveWorkbook` may be pointing to an unrelated workbook.
2. `Sheets("Analisis").Range("G1")` is open to user-editing. If the sheet has not been protected, the user may have unintentionally deleted the text contained in that cell.

I would suggest a line that checks if `Name` is blank and provides a default value to `Name` in the case that it is indeed blank.

```vb
Sub SaveTool()

Dim Name As String
Dim sFileSaveName As Variant

Name = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Analisis").Range("G1")

If Trim(Name) = "" Then Name = "DefaultFileName"

sFileSaveName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=Name, FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xlsm), *.xlsm")

If sFileSaveName <> False Then
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs sFileSaveName
End If

End Sub
```

I have added a test to maybe help you in debugging why this does not seem to work for you and your files:

Open a blank workbook and try this code - press Save on the pop-up windows without typing anything:

```vb
Sub test()
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add
        .Name = "Analisis"
        .Range("G1").Value = "Test_File_Name"
    End With
    
    Dim Name As String
    Dim sFileSaveName As Variant
    
    Name = "Test_File_Name"
    Debug.Print "1a - " & Name
    sFileSaveName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=Name, FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xlsm), *.xlsm")
    Debug.Print "1b - " & sFileSaveName
    
    Name = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Analisis").Range("G1").Value
    Debug.Print "2a - " & Name
    sFileSaveName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=Name, FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xlsm), *.xlsm")
    Debug.Print "2b - " & sFileSaveName
End Sub
```

The output should be:

```vb
'1a - Test_File_Name
'1b - C:\Users\Username\Documents\Test_File_Name.xlsm
'2a - Test_File_Name
'2b - C:\Users\Username\Documents\Test_File_Name.xlsm
```

Now remove the `With` block from the test and put the code into your project file. The differences in output should help you narrow down the cause of your problems.

Comment: Hello @Toddleson. Thanks for the answer. I changed to ThisWorkbook and added the the check line, but I’m still getting the name on Blank. I added a line with a Message Box to test if the name had been copied from the cell, the sheet it’s blocked, and I get the name on the Box but not on the Save As window.

Comment: @Henry274 I have added a troubleshooting test script, please see my revised answer

Comment: Hello @Toddleson. I made the test as you suggested, the output on the blank file it the same as yours. When I add the test to my code, I get this Out Put:
`'1a - Test_File_Name`
`'1b - C:\Users\Username\Downloads`
 `'2a -`
`'2b - C:\Users\Username\Downloads`

The las folder opened using the excel was downloads.
I don´t know why the value of Name variable shows as blank, when I put it on a Message Box it shows the information on the cell. (I’m not an expert on VBA, your help it’s great).

Comment: Please add an example of your debugging code with the messagebox  to your original post. There may be some clues in there as to why the text is displayed in the `MessageBox` but not in the `GetSaveAsFilename`

Answer (score 1):

The problems where the special characters on the name to be assigned!
I added a function to remove them with blank spaces and now it works!
This is the final code:

```
Function ValidFileName(text As String) As String
    text = Replace(text, "\", "")
    text = Replace(text, "/", "")
    text = Replace(text, "[", "")
    text = Replace(text, "]", "")
    text = Replace(text, ":", "")
    text = Replace(text, "?", "")
    text = Replace(text, ".", "")
    text = Replace(text, ",", "")
        ValidFileName = text
End Function
Sub SaveTool()

Dim ToolName As String
Dim sFileSaveName As Variant


ToolName = ValidFileName(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Analisis").Range("G1").Value)

sFileSaveName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=ToolName, FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xlsm), *.xlsm")

If sFileSaveName <> False Then
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs sFileSaveName
End If

End Sub
```

Thank you @Toddleson for your help!